# IBM x3650 M3: can an installed vanilla vSphere 5.1u1 be replaced with "vSphere enhanced for IBM"?

Tags: vmware-vsphere, ibm-xseries

Some 4 years ago we got the free vSphere Hypervison 5.0 (ESXi) directly from the VMWare for installation on a donated IBM x3650 M3 server. Basically, we are novices in both IBM server management as well as vSphere, but somehow we managed to install this thing and throw in some 5 VMs. We also installed the free license and all went fine. With upgrading over the last years, server is now on vSphere 5.1 update 1.

After having to examine a possible disk fault on the disk mirror, we updated the various firmware of the box. In the process though, we discovered that IBM provides versions of vSphere/ESXi that include customizations for its server systems (see http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/x/os/vmware/ ).

The questions here are:

1. Can one upgrade from the "vanilla" vSphere 5.1 update 1, to the
   equivalent IBM version *without* reinstalling from scratch?
2. If it can be done, are there any documentation on how to go about
   it? Is it a safe procedure?
3. Finally, will this change void the license key of the free
   version we are using?

Thank you in advance for any info provided.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can to an "upgrade" from the same version to the same version for [OEM], but if you were to upgrade to a higher version at the same time as going over to the ESXi for IBM version, it would be exactly the same as a normal upgrade.

Comment: I would assume that if such documentation exists, that IBM support would know where to find it. If not, they would be the go-to source for, well, support :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes... Just as with HP or Dell, you can [safely upgrade to a newer version (with hardware-specific extensions)](http://darrylmiles.wordpress.com/2012/02/20/ibms-cusomized-esxi-5-0-faqs/) on a standalone host by using the vendor-provided .ISO.

HP and Dell also allow you to download and install the handful of additional .VIB software packages to bring a generic ESXi installation to a version with vendor hardware support. IBM only seems to allow this through the vSphere Update Manager, which you wouldn't have on a single host setup.

There are no licensing implications here.